# Windows 11 USB creator

Tags: usb, mount

I downloaded Win 11 .iso  - I now need a disk mounting app such as Etcher,  Woe-USB, etc.  However NONE of these are available on Elementary or the SNAPD store.  Anyone know what I can do as there is no MIDI software on Linux and I want to create music so I can only do this on Windows unfortunately.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the return-to-Windows question, but there are plenty of Linux applications that will work with MIDI. Off the top of my head, I can think of [Ardour](https://ardour.org/), [Bitwig Studio](https://www.musicianwave.com/go/bitwig-studio/), [Renoise](https://www.renoise.com/), [Reaper](https://www.reaper.fm/), and [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/). There's even [Ubuntu Studio](https://ubuntustudio.org/), a distribution of Ubuntu wholly focused on audio and video content creation. Is there something in particular missing that only Windows tools can offer?

Comment: I got Bitwig with my Midi as a freebie, it does say Linux download but it is debian and I can't seem to run it.

Answer (score 0):

You can download Etcher from here https://www.balena.io/etcher/

It's an appimage file and I've never managed to make it work, but I hope you'll have a different experience.

Comment: thanks, I can't get it to work either.  Says missing partition table and may not be recognized as bootable. I used GParted to format USB to NTFS but no good.

Answer (score 0):

You can download etcher from:

https://balena.io/etcher

I have done so and it works perfectly OK (for me) and is very easy to use.

https://itsfoss.com/use-appimage-linux/

Comment: thanks, I can't get it to work. Says missing partition table and may not be recognized as bootable. I used GParted to format USB to NTFS but no good.